# Get the form of the clicked link with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the form object containg the button which I clicked? I do not want to give the form an id.

```
$('#buttonid@(Model.Id)').on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 // get form here which is around the link button I clicked?              

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to find a parent element matching a given selector:

```
$('#buttonid@(Model.Id)').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    // do something with $form...
});
```

Comment: How can I get the form element to serialize it then? Doing $form.serialize() returns an empty string like "" ???

Comment: That should definitely work. Can you add your full HTML to the question.